# Internet Explorer shows one textbox different size with HTML size attribute

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have two `<input>` fields with the HTML attribute `size=20`.

This displays fine in Mozilla Firefox; the two text fields have the same size.

Internet Explorer shows one bigger than the other.

Can you help me there?

```
<td>Login</td><td><input type="text" name="login" size="20"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="psw" size="20"/>
```

Comment: Please post your code or provide a link.

Comment: Can you pleas share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tell you what I told somebody else earlier on, you may benefit from a reset.css in your page, as I.E. is a niggly so and so it sometimes looks a lot different than other browsers. This is the reset I would normally use:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

This should make it look a bit better, if that doesn't work, you're going to need a seperate css file for internet explorer.

Comment: how can i use a seperate css file?

Comment: You can have as many stylesheets as you like, you simply link then as you would any other, just ensure that the reset.css come first, so it would look a little like this:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/Reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/MainStyle.css" />

Just ensure they're looking at the right directories or the root and that they are placed in the <head></head> tags of your HTML or master page.

Answer (score 0):

Set your width in pixels instead like

```
<br>input.text {background-color:#fffafa; border:dotted 1px #555; width:230px;} <br>
```

Then you should have solved the problem.